# selecting properties from other table with Lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I am less experienced with Lambda expression for .NET and trying to get data from SQL using lambda expression. With below query, I am able to get data back, but do not want to use `include` to get all properties from other tables.

```
public IEnumerable<ResourceGroup> GetAllServersByApplication(string application_name, string environment_name, string status)
{
    var query = _context.ResourceGroup
        .Include(a => a.Application)
        .Include(t => t.Type)
        .Include(e => e.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(e => e.Environment)
        .Include(s => s.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(s => s.Server)
        .Include(s => s.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(s => s.Server).ThenInclude(s => s.Status)
        .Where(a => a.Application.Name == application_name && a.ServersGroup.Any(s => s.Environment.Name == environment_name && s.Server.Status.Name == status))
        .ToList();

    return query;
}
```

Lets take an example of below include statement.

```
.Include(s => s.ServersGroup).ThenInclude(s => s.Server)
```

From `s.Server`, I only want to select `Id,ServerName,Status, and IPAddress`. These are the properties from `Servers` class that I created as a model.

What is the easy way to exclude all the includes and only show properties that I am interested in?

**Here are my tables and its properties:**

**Status** table:

```
Id, Name
```

**Application** table:

```
Id, Name
```

**Servers** table:

```
Id, ServerName, Status
```

**Environments** table:

```
Id, Name
```

**ResourceGroup** table:

```
Id, Name, Application_Id, Environment_Id
```

**ServersResourceGroup** table:

```
Id, Server_Id, Resource_Id
```

**UPDATE 1**:

```
var query = _context.ResourceGroup
                    .SelectMany(rg => rg.ServersGroup
                    .Select(sg => new
                    {
                        ResourceName = rg.Name,
                        ApplicationName = rg.Application.Name,
                        ServerName = sg.Server.ServerName,
                        EnvironmentName = sg.Environment.Name,
                        Status = sg.Server.Status.Name
                    })).Where(a => a.ApplicationName == application_name && a.EnvironmentName == environment_name && a.Status == status).ToList();
        return query;
```

And error from red line on `query` variable:
[image]

**UPDATE 2**:

Here is the query syntax:

```
var query = from rg in _context.ResourceGroup
                    let app = rg.Application
                    from sg in rg.ServersGroup
                    let env = sg.Environment
                    let srv = sg.Server
                    let stat = srv.Status
                    where app.Name == application_name
                            && rg.ServersGroup.Any(s => s.Environment.Name == environment_name
                                      && s.Server.Status.Name == status)
                    select new
                    {
                        ResourceGroupName = rg.Name,
                        ApplicationName = app.Name,
                        ServerName = srv.ServerName,
                        Alias = srv.Alias,
                        IPAddress = srv.IPAddress,
                        Type = rg.Type.Name,
                        Status = stat.Name
                    };
        return query;
```

Here is the red line error I get in query variable:

[image]

Your help is really appreciated. :)

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: EF cannot partially load an association property using include, so you need to project this into a view model (or anonymous object) using `.Select()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thank you for your response. I have updated my question with more details. If I remove all `Includes`, how do I syntax select statement using lambda? I can write it in native sql query, which is very simple, but lambda is making me confusing.

Comment: Keep the includes (depending if lazy loading is enabled or not), but then use a `.Select(x => new MyModel(){ // set values here });` where `MyModel` is a class containing only those properties/collections that you want to include in the view.

Answer (score 1):

With lambda expressions, you can use `SelectMany` to flatten 1-n associations into a 1 dimensional list (i.e. parent and child properties side-by-side). In your case, judging from the `Where` clause, I think only `ResourceGroup` - `ServerGroup` is 1 - n, so it should be something like:

```
var query = _context.ResourceGroup
                    .SelectMany
                     (
                          rg => rg.ServersGroup
                                  .Select(sg => new 
                                  {
                                      ResourceGroup = rg.Name,
                                      Application = rg.Application.Name,
                                      Server = sg.Server.ServerName,
                                      // etc.
                                  })
                     )
```

Of course it's good to know how to use lambda expressions, but there's really no point in using them when query syntax makes for much better comprehensible code.

The equivalent in query syntax is:

```
var query = from rg in _context.ResourceGroup
            let app = rg.Application
            from sg in rg.ServersGroup
            let env = sg.Environment
            let srv = sg.Server
            let stat = srv.Status
            where app.Name == application_name
               && sg.ServersGroup.Any(s => s.Environment.Name == environment_name
                                        && s.Server.Status.Name == status)
            select new
            {
                ResourceGroup = rg.Name,
                Application = app.Name,
                Server = srv.ServerName,
                // etc. use any property from rg, app, sg, srv, stat
            };
```

As you see -

- n - 1 associations are represented by a `let` statement (which really only helps here to shorten the references in the `select`)
- 1-n associations are represented by the `from ... from` syntax, which is query syntax for `SelectMany`.

I didn't change the `Where` clause in the query syntax. *Maybe* you can use ...

```
            where app.Name == application_name
               && env.Name == environment_name
               && stat.Name == status)
```

... but note that this is different. The original `where` returns all `ResourceGroup` having *at least* one `ServerGroup` meeting the condition (and maybe other groups with different environments and statuses). The other `where` only returns data with environments and statuses equal to the search parameters.

Comment: first of all thank you so much for taking time for explaining me both lambda and query syntax. I think query syntax are much more readable as compare to lambda syntax. I tried both approach and I am getting a red line that it cannot be to IEnumarable. I have updated my query with Update 1 status that contains first lambda expression query that was suggested in your answer. I will add update two shortly with query syntax.

Comment: The error tells you that you want to return `IEnumerable<ResourceGroup>` from your method, while the query returns anonymous types. Your wish to return only selected properties and the requirement to return `ResourceGroup`s (with adhering objects) are incompatible. If you want to return selected properties you have to return a collection of some custom class that contains the properties you need. (Returning anonymous types from methods isn't recommended).

Comment: understood, so in that case I can either keep my original query or modify my method to use `List<T>`?

Comment: That's right. You can't have both. Personally, I'd lean to using a custom projection (say, DTO class). Includes can hit performance badly.

Comment: make sense. Thank you Gert for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Don't `Include` all the related tables, but `Select` all the fields you need. You might find it easier to make a new class to hold the data.

Sorry if I can't make a real query statement here, but your question doens't specify the fields you need.